# Disabling the rollover effect on tables with the Substance L&F

Tags: java, swing, jtable, substance

Is there a way to disable the rollover effect of the Substance look and feel on the hovered rows of a table?

I tried to disable the animation but the rows are still highlighted:

```
AnimationConfigurationManager.getInstance().disallowAnimations(AnimationFacet.ROLLOVER);
```

I'm using the Nebula skin.

Thank you

Comment: I'm searching once time for that (really never needed or use that) but this is about HighLighter ??? EDIT : but you can test that, where is difference, create own Renderer, but not extend that with SubxtanceXxxRenderer but with DefaultXxxRenderer, then HightLighter doesn't works on renderered Column(s) or Cell(s)

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, unfortunately custom renderers bring other issues with Substance. If the renderer simply extends DefaultTableCellRenderer the row stripping is lost.